# Exclude taxonomy terms from being choosen in facets

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I am working on a search field with a facet which has a list of taxonomy terms.

Some taxonomy terms I want to exclude from being choosen, because it is not relevant for people to know about.

How can I exclude taxonomy terms in a facet so people can't choose them while searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

At this page: `/admin/config/search/facets/(facet name)/edit`, there's something called `Exclude specified items`.

That's the place where I can exclude taxonomy terms.